# Pop up notification with animation behind tab bar

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I'd like to create a pop up notification that appears behind a tab bar, animates to just above it, then goes back down again before being removed from the superview.

I'd like this to all happen from inside the app delegate. I've got a function to do some of this, which looks like this:

```
func displayPopupNotification(message: String) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        // get the currently active view controller
        var vc = self.window!.rootViewController

        if(vc is UINavigationController){
            vc = (vc as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController
        }

        // set up the notification with it's label
        let notificationView = UIView()
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = message
        label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        label.font = uifont_notification
        notificationView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        notificationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        notificationView.alpha = 0 // ready for fading in
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // add the notification view to the view controller            
        vc!.view.addSubview(notificationView)

        // add the label to the notification
        notificationView.addSubview(label)

        // set constraints up 
        vc!.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[subview(60)]-(-60@999)-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics:nil, views:["subview":notificationView]))
        vc!.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[subview]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics:nil, views:["subview":notificationView]))
        notificationView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|-0-[subview]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics:nil, views:["subview":label]))
        notificationView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-0-[subview]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics:nil, views:["subview":label]))

        // animate the pop up
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay:0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone,
            animations: {notificationView.alpha = 1.0},
            completion: {(value: Bool) in
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay:2.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionNone, animations: {notificationView.alpha = 0.0},
                    completion: {(value: Bool) in
                        notificationView.removeFromSuperview()
                })
            }
        )      
    })
}
```

In this code, the notification fades in and out again, so that's a good start. Here's what it looks like:

[image: The notification view]

However, I'd really like it to be behind the tab bar, animate up, wait for a second and then animate down again.

I attempted to do this by changing constraints, so the starting constraint was this:

```
V:[subview(60)]-(-60@999)-|
```

And then it was animated like this:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(10,
            animations: {vc!.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[subview(60)]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics:nil, views:["subview":notificationView]))}
        )
```

But that didn't work - it just instantly snaps to the second constraint.

Questions:

1. Can you animate constraints like this (and what did I do wrong if so)
2. How can I make the view appear behind the tab bar

Answer (score -1):

If you animate constraints in an `UIView.animateWithDuration` block, you have to call `[view setNeedsLayout];` in the animation block for the animation to happen.

As for getting the view behind the tab bar, you could also use a different approach: Add the view to the content view (the view above the tab bar), and move it in on the bottom of that view. If that view clips its contents, it will appear as if the view slides in from under the tab bar.

Comment: Thanks for you advice, that doesn't seem to work though. I'm also not sure what you mean by the content view - how would I do that? Sorry if I'm being stupid - I've only been learning this a few weeks.

Comment: I mean the view that shows your content and changes when you press a tab - you should attach the view you want to move in to the bottom of that view (constraint from bottom of the view you want to move in to the bottom of the content view, with constant value of -(height of view to move in), then change the constant value to 0 to animate it in.